# How to make sound alert when new notification came and app is in foreground using RN firebase push notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am trying to get notification sound in foreground but it not works, to achieve that i have added default sound property at server side and its working fine in kill mode and background mode of app but not working in foreground mode. expecting quick response from community. Thanks

Comment: sound will by default ring but you have to make sure few things first of all check your phone is not on silent mode secondly check the code you have default sound in your code, third sending notification from firebase cloud messaging option counter check the sound is enabled from there

Comment: @ZaidQureshi Thanks for the reply, as i added in description, sound is working in background and kill mode. its just issue when app is in foreground mode where not getting sound of notification.

Comment: Please add sample code that is working in background & kill mode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.